# Detect discrepancies between two sequences

Tags: r

I have two time series vectors: `complete_data` and `incomplete_data`. the data in the vector consists of 6 possible events which occur randomly throughout the vector. In principle the two should be the same because with every event in `complete_data`, that same event was then added on to `incomplete_data`. however in reality there were some anomalies in the system and not all of the events in `complete_data` were sent to `incomplete_data`. Thus `complete_data` is longer than `incomplete_data`. I need to find the differences in the pattern between the two and mark them. I made an attempt but it assumes that the discrepancy between the two vectors occurs in a single chunk, whereas in reality, there are various "missing events" scattered in `incomplete_data`.

Here is my attempt:

```
complete_data <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')
dfcomplete <- as.data.frame(complete_data)
incomplete_data <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a','c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c')
dfincomplete <- as.data.frame(incomplete_data)

findMatch <- function(complete_data, incomplete_data){

  matching_inorder <- NULL
  matching_reverseorder <- NULL

  for (i in 1:length(complete_data)){
    matching_inorder[i] <- complete_data[i] == incomplete_data[i]
    matching_reverseorder[i] <- rev(complete_data)[i] == rev(incomplete_data)[i]
  }

  is_match <- ifelse(matching_inorder == FALSE & 
                       rev(matching_reverseorder) == FALSE, 'non_match', 'match')
  is_match
}

dfcomplete$is_match_incorrect <- findMatch(dfcomplete$complete_data,
                                 dfincomplete$incomplete_data)
```

And here is what I would like to get:

```
dfcomplete$expected_output <- c('match', 'match', 'match', 'match', 'non-match', 'match',
                 'match', 'match', 'non_match', 'match', 'match', 'match')
```

In reality my data is much larger than these examples with many different discrepancies scattered throughout the vector. Though there aren't necessarily too many discrepancies to make the task meaningless, for example, in one case the `complete` vector has 320 datapoints whilst the `incomplete` vector has 309.

Any help that can be offered would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various ways to do this, but here's a recursive one, where `x` is assumed to be a complete sequence and `y` incomplete.

```
compare <- function(x, y) {
  if (length(x) > 0) {
    if (x[1] == y[1]) {
      x[1] <- "match"
      c(x[1], compare(x[-1], y[-1]))
    } else {
      x[1] <- "no match"
      c(x[1], compare(x[-1], y))
    }
  }
}
compare(complete_data, incomplete_data)
# [1] "match"    "match"    "match"    "match"    "no match" "match"   
# [7] "match"    "match"    "no match" "match"    "match"    "match"
```

Another one that perhaps is more readable and uses a simple loop would be

```
out <- rep(NA, length(incomplete_data))
gap <- 0
for(i in seq_along(complete_data)) {
  if (complete_data[i] == incomplete_data[i - gap]) {
    out[i] <- "match"
  } else {
    out[i] <- "no match"
    gap <- gap + 1
  }
}
out
# [1] "match"    "match"    "match"    "match"    "no match" "match"   
# [7] "match"    "match"    "no match" "match"    "match"    "match"
```

Comment: Indeed, as I said `x` is assumed to be a complete sequence, meaning that it's at least as long as `y`.

Comment: @stevezissou, and how is that a problem? In my solutions `y` and `incomplete_data` are shorter (or of equal length) than `x` and `complete_data`, respectively, which is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you can afford having event names only one letter long, here is a solution using string matching. The trick is to transform the incomplete data to a pattern including places to insert new characters.

```
complete_data <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'B', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'C', 'a', 'b', 'c')
dfcomplete <- as.data.frame(complete_data,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
incomplete_data <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'a','c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c')

y <- paste0('^(.*)',paste(incomplete_data,collapse='(.*)'),'(.*)$')
x <- paste(complete_data,collapse="")
z <- str_length(str_match(x,y)[-1])

data.frame(incomplete_data=c("",incomplete_data),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  mutate(n=ifelse(incomplete_data=="",z,z+1)) %>%
  filter(n>0) %>%
  uncount(n) %>%
  mutate(incomplete_data=ifelse(str_detect(rownames(.),"\\."),"",incomplete_data)) %>%
  bind_cols(dfcomplete) %>%
  mutate(match=complete_data==incomplete_data)
#   incomplete_data complete_data match
#1                a             a  TRUE
#2                b             b  TRUE
#3                c             c  TRUE
#4                a             a  TRUE
#5                              B FALSE
#6                c             c  TRUE
#7                a             a  TRUE
#8                b             b  TRUE
#9                              C FALSE
#10               a             a  TRUE
#11               b             b  TRUE
#12               c             c  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks great!